# Asp.NET MVC Route Performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have an application with a couple thousand routes.

This is because for each product we use a custom URL, as opposed to the textbook /product/id.

With this many urls, the performance is unacceptable in the router.

I am trying to find ways to improve it, but I am drawing a blank.

I have about 20 regex routes and about 3 thousand unique url routes.

Any Ideas?

Sorry for being so open ended, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Can you explain what *specifically* is the source of the performance bottleneck?  If you cannot, you haven't done enough profiling yet.

Comment: I have used haacks route debugger and set timestamps to measure the performance.  I have moved my routes around (order) and it is improved somewhat, but the routes that are added last are really slow.

Comment: The other issue that I have is that I do not know how to profile the router itself

Comment: im assuming you've already removed unused view engines?

Comment: we are only using razor, but how can I remove the other engines.  Also can that improve the router performance?

Comment: in `Application_Start`: `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear(); ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());`  This will make it only look for .cshtml files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your urls are all on the format yoursite.com/{url}, you can still store all the three thousand urls in the database, and create a custom controller factory which uses the {url} parameter to look the correct information up in the database and assign correct controller, action and any parameters you're using.

There are lots of posts on [google](http://www.google.se/search?q=create+your+own+controllerfactory) on how to implement the controller factory.

I imagine you'll also want some parsing of the existing routes to put them all in the database - this can probably be done by iterating over the `RouteTable` after you instantiate your application (i.e. after `RegisterRoutes()` is called).

Comment: This is similar to what we used to have, let me check it out.  IE, I am thinking that if I hit the default controller then I can check if that url is in a hashtable and route to the appropriate controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the 3 thousand unique url routes and replace them with a generic route that is the last catch-all route.  Something like:

```
routes.MapRoute("productRoute", "{category}/{manufacturer}/{productTitle}", new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional, manufacturer = UrlParameter.Optional, productTitle = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

You could also then add a custom IRouteConstraint to validate that the category exists (but just make sure it doesn't hit your database every time or performance will degrade).

Comment: I had mentioned that I do not have academic routes:  "This is because for each product we use a custom URL, as opposed to the textbook /product/id"

Comment: Do you literally hand type each url each time you add a new product?  You should still be able to translate them to a generic route.

Comment: Yes, for SEO we enter a custom url for each product that we offer.  For instance we have something like /air-filter/some-manfacturer-url.  We might also have /brake/some-braker-maker.

Comment: Let me try this, the problem I have with this is the number (2000) os urls that use a unique url that relates to an index.  We used to look it up in a hashtable, so it was fast.  again, let me try it.

Comment: @hivie7510 why would you not store that slug(url) in the product table?  if you did, then you wouldn't need that many routes and still get good readable urls, this is how several blogs work.

Comment: @Joakim  That is what we do, do you have some insight into what the blogs use for routes.  I agree that they have a similar problem

Comment: @hivie7510 one of the routes I've seen allot is "Archive/{year}/{month}/{day}/{slug}", that way blogs usually get around that a post could have the same slug, so as long as you have a way of making it truly unique then you should be able to make that kind of generic route. (in other words the slug would be used as an id)

Comment: @hivie7510 No, blogs do not have a "problem" with this. They use the slug as the key... not as a route.